# expressjs conditional redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, express

I'm trying to write middleware for authentication. And I want this if statement to redirect the user to `'/'` if they're **not** logged in. If they're logged in, I wan't to redirect them to '/news'.

```
/*Simplified for this example*/

if(rs.authenticated === true) {
    next();
} else {
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Is there a way to do this inside of these if statements? Or do I have to write a new method? I've tried several ways with if statements but I just get redirect loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard pattern would be for all pages requiring a logged-in user to use a middleware that verifies a logged-in user and redirects to `/` if they are not logged in.

```
function loggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if(req.authenticated === true) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
}

app.get('/news', loggedIn, newsRoute);
app.get('/', homeRoute);
```

Your problem is you are using a middleware for all routes, when you really only want to use it for protected routes, which is where your redirect loop is happening. If you want to send logged-in users to '/news' instead of '/', you can either just render the right template or do a conditional redirect in there.

```
function homeRoute(req, res) {
  if (req.authenticated) {
      return res.redirect('/news');
  }
  res.render('home');
}
```

Comment: The if statement in my example is actually from a method (I use it for protected routes, auth.restrict), and I have another method called logged_in that I use for non protected routes so if they are already logged in they get redirected to '/news' instead of staying at the login page for example. I was just thinking if I could use one method for all routes. But then maybe using two separate methods is the better choice?

Comment: Well you need logic to avoid a redirect loop, so you'll either need to examine `req.path` and only redirect them to '/' if they aren't already requesting '/', or follow my suggestion.

Comment: If I just render the view, and not redirecting, no data will be passed to it. Is there a way around that?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think that question through. It's about reusing code. But thats a separate topic so I'll post a new question for that. Thanks

Comment: If you want to have some route effectively be identical to another route without a redirect (possible based on conditional logic), make your route handler a named function and just call it: `app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {newsRoute(req, res, next);});`

Answer (score -1):

You want to introduce a small middleware for checking if the user is logged in. You set it up on a route handler level.

Please see those SO answers:

[javascript node.js next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384526/javascript-node-js-next)

[How does Express/Connect middleware work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881656/how-does-express-connect-middleware-work)

[What is the parameter "next" used for in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/node-js-express-next)

Comment: Not enough content *in the answer itself* to be useful - links can go stale. The OP says they are using middleware already